# How to insert different files in different columns using a query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I want to add files to the database.

I have 6 columns to store files. If only 1 file is uploaded, I want to upload the single file in only one column. If two files are uploaded I want to use 2 columns.

What should my SQL query be to update accordingly when the files are uploaded?

[image: the 6 columns in my database]

I have restricted the number of files uploaded to 6 and their total size to 2 MB.

I'm using ASP.NET.

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (fileUpload.PostedFiles.Count <= 6)
            {
                int a = fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                if (a < 2000)
                {
                    foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in fileUpload.PostedFiles)
                    {
                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                        string contentType = postedFile.ContentType;
                        using (Stream fs = postedFile.InputStream)
                        {
                            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                            {
                                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

                                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= USER\SQLEXPRESS ; Initial Catalog= BlobUploading ; Integrated Security = True"))
                                {
                                    string query = "insert into tblBlob values (@BloB1, @BloB2, @BloB3,@BloB4 ,@BloB5 ,@BloB6)";
                                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                                    {
                                        cmd.Connection = con;
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloB1", bytes[0]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloB2", bytes[1]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloB3", bytes[2]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloB4", bytes[3]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloB5", bytes[4]);
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloB6", bytes[5]);
                                    con.Open();
                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    con.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is my update code, i know that inserting the values of bytes into the table is wrong!

Comment: storing binary objects in a sql server is maybe not the best option

Comment: As you have nullable columns in your table, anything special in your query is necessary, just pass null in query when you don't have a file to upload. I think you should also consider create a table with only FormId and a Blob field, instead of 6 nullable fields

Comment: Not an answer, but a relevant comment: Is SQL Server ***Express*** the correct choice for you?  The normal approach would be to store the URLs and the client/application load the BLOBs from there instead *(file servers being better at servicing such things)*.

Comment: Show your code. It's as simple as adding a few `if ()` statements and assigning the proper parameters. Also, numbered columns often are an indication that you can benefit from normalization.

Comment: The correct way to store an unknown number of the same thing in a DB is not with multiple columns, but by having a table that you can insert multiple rows.  You can normalize this by having a table with just the `FormID`, a `FileId` and the `Blob` column (though storing a URL would be a better idea).  Then the `FormId` can be a foreign key to the original table (if it has other  columns)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your insert query into a Stored Procedure. In Stored Procedure, set the default value of Blob to Null.

From ASP.NET, set the blob parameters according to the availability of file. If you do not set a blob parameter, then it will be set to null in SP.

```
string strQuery = "sp_SaveFile";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@FormId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = fileId;
if(bytes1 != null)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Blob1", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes1;
if(bytes2 != null)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Blob2", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes2;
// .... Handle rest of the Blob parameters.

InsertUpdateData(cmd);
```

Comment: This may be what is being asked for but a better design is to have a single blob column rather than six. Any consequent processing could be a nightmare having to test each row to see how many of the columns have data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redesign your database structure so that there is only one blob field, a record ID field as PK and a load identifier to identify which file if there are multiple files. Your insert query might look like:

```
INSERT INTO myTable
(
    fileID,
    fileContents
)
VALUES
(1, fileContent1),
(2 ,fileContent2)
```

You can then vary the number of added records depending on how many are needed.

Insert multiple rows, not multiple columns as @juharr says.

To do this in ASP.NET, C# you need structure to hold your files:

```
public class FileHolder
{
    int FileID {get; set; }
    byte[] FileData {get; set;}
}
```

Create a `List<FileHolder> files` to hold the data. Then:

```
foreach (var item in files)
{
    // write item.FileID and item.FileData
    // into your table
}
```

You are then not restricted to the number of files you can process at any one time.

Comment: They either need the `FormID` as well or another table that maps `FormID` to it's files.

Comment: i couldn't get the part where you mentioned that i should have only one blob field wherein i can store many files, sorry i'm new to this, can you elaborate it a bit more, and my coding part is pending since i couldn't solve this issue.

Comment: I'm converting the files into bytes and storing them

Comment: @Grijan Basically if you have a table with one column for your file then when you store 2 files you insert two rows.  When you store 5 files you insert 5 rows.  Then you can query by the `FormID` to get back zero or more rows that match and contain the files.

Comment: i completely undestand that @juharr but i was assigned to do as i mentioned above, is it possible?

Comment: @Grijan Sure, you'd just need a bunch of `if` statements to handle the finite number of files you can insert.  Either having 6 slightly different SQL queries or one and set the extra parameters to null.

Comment: @juharr even im thinking of the same or maybe going with a switch case but i thought i will have a single query to accomplish this, i will update what i did by the end of the day!

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (fileUpload.PostedFiles.Count <= 6)
            {
                int a = fileUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                if (a < 2000)
                {
                    foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in fileUpload.PostedFiles)
                    {
                        string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                        string contentType = postedFile.ContentType;
                        using (Stream fs = postedFile.InputStream)
                        {
                            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                            {
                                byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

                                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source= USER\SQLEXPRESS ; Initial Catalog= BlobUploading ; Integrated Security = True"))
                                {
                                    string query = "insert into tblBlob values (@BloB1, @BloB2, @BloB3,@BloB4 ,@BloB5 ,@BloB6)";
                                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                                    {
                                        cmd.Connection = con;
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloB1", bytes[0]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloB2", bytes[1]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloB3", bytes[2]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloB4", bytes[3]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloB5", bytes[4]);
                                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BloB6", bytes[5]);
                                        con.Open();
                                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                        con.Close();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This is my update code, i know that inserting the values of bytes into the table is wrong!